# ViewPager inside GridView Android

Tags: android, image, gridview, android-viewpager

I am creating a app where i need to deal with images.

Here what i need is to implement view-pager inside grid-view.

I have seen many examples on Google but in all examples ,when the image gets clicked in grid-view  a new activity gets called and where the implementation of view-pager performed.

What exactly is need to implement view-pager inside grid-view so when a image gets called there is no new activity created.

Comment: you can also use Horizontal Scroll View inside gridview